# What is Chipmunk? (Apart from being a Physics Engine)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

Hopefully, this question isn't a dumb as I fear it sounds, but it may still be pretty dumb.

I'm new to Objective-C, and Cocoa. In fact, I'm completely new to C in general. I'm trying to implement an iPhone game using [Cocos2d-iPhone](http://www.sapusmedia.com/cocos2d-iphone-api-doc/). It's a game I've made before in Flash, so I thought it would be a nice way to lean Objective C, cocoa and cocos2d.

One thing I am having a big problem with is understanding why all the [Chipmunk](http://wiki.slembcke.net/main/published/Chipmunk) code looks different to all the normal Objective-C stuff. For example, there's stuff like

```
chipmunkBody->position.x
```

which I thought would have been

`chipmunkBody.position.x` or maybe `[[chipmunkBody position] x]` (bad example maybe).

One way this keeps on biting me in the ass is with cpVect. cpVect is pretty important, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to pass it around. CGPoint, no problem, I can make pointers, pass them around in methods and what not, but the second I use cpVect instead, it's "welcome to Errorville, population you".

So that's the question, what is Chipmunk, so I can start finding out more about working with it.

thanks
-t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Chipmunk, but it's probably written in C/C++. That's the reason.

**EDIT:** Yup, it's written in C.

`chipmunkBody` is a pointer to a struct, and the arrow operator (`->`) is how you access the members of a struct through a pointer to the struct in C.

Comment: at the risk of oversimplifying something I'm worried might be ridiculously complex, what should I be aware of when mixing C and Objective-C?

Comment: I think you should post that as a separate question. I haven't personally mixed C/C++ and Objective-C before, and therefore I'm not aware of any pitfalls.

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C, so there is really no concept of mixing them. They're pre-mixed. Just be aware that the C code is there.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're looking for an easy way to use Chipmunk thru way of Objective-C, Theres a nice little post about an Objective-C class called SpaceManager here: http://www.mobile-bros.com/?p=126