# Is there any physics engine SDK for iPhone/iPod touch and iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod-touch

Is there any physics engine SDK for iPhone/iPod touch and iPad?

Comment: [This post might be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715149/what-is-chipmunk-apart-from-being-a-physics-engine). (It's not really a duplicate of this question.)

Comment: If you're looking for an Objective-C version of Box2D, try Boxjective2D: http://www.koboldtouch.com/display/KTD/Objective-C+Physics+Engine

Answer (score 5):

The [Chipmunk engine](http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-physics/) is written in C, and they've even provided an Objective-C wrapper.

The [Box2D engine](http://www.box2d.org/) is written in C++, and so it can be compiled/linked into an iPhone OS project by telling Xcode to treat it as Objective-C++.

Both are excellent. (I've only extensively used Box2D, but I've heard great things about Chipmunk too.)

Answer (score 3):

I've used the SIO2 engine for developing games on the iPhone, and it uses the open-source physics engine [bullet](http://bulletphysics.org/).  I'm not sure if all the soft-body features are available, but certainly the rigid body ones are. I don't know if anybody has written an Objective-C wrapper, but you certainly don't need one.