# Best games/physics engines to use?

Tags: iphone, android, physics

Looking for games/physics engines to use for mobile game development.

- iPhone there is
  [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/)
- Android I've found
  [RokonAndroid](http://rokonandroid.com)

Just wondering if there are any others (better ones) that anyone knows of? Or any that are more cross-compatible?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: See also [Is there any physics engine SDK for iPhone/iPod touch and iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695724/is-there-any-physics-engine-sdk-for-iphone-ipod-touch-and-ipad) and [Chipmunk Physics or Box2D for C++ 2D GameEngine ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707106/chipmunk-physics-or-box2d-for-c-2d-gameengine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AndEngine by the anddev.org team..its alpha with no binary release..you will have to build from source..

AndEngine.org I believe

Comment: Nice, haven't heard of this one.

Answer (score 1):

I used cocos2D-android and andengine. Andengine is much better. Best perfomance and almost without errors.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually coded with either of these yet, but I did get the Bullet engine to compile with the NDK a few months ago.  I forget what was involved off the top of my head (I can edit this post if needed), but I remember it was a bit involved and took me a couple days to solve.

- [Box2D port for Android](http://www.4feets.com/2009/03/2d-physics-on-android-using-box2d/)
- [Bullet port for Android](http://apistudios.com/hosted/marzec/badlogic/wordpress/?p=248)

Comment: Box2D is now integrated into AndEngine too :)

Answer (score 1):

Tom - not sure if it's better or not, but [Gideros Studio](http://www.giderosmobile.com) may answer your needs. It's a cross-platform mobile development environment with physics, in-app purchase, Gamecenter, Storekit, hardware, as well as tweening, particle engine, and many 3rd party IDEs like physics editor, sprite helper and level editors.

It also supports native code (plugins), meaning if you have a library in C, C++, Objective C or Java, you ca integrate it next to Lua, the programming language Gideros Studio is based on. Moroever Gideros Studio IDE uses over-the-air (Wi-Fi) testing, so it's possible to test the application instantly on a real hardware.

It uses Box2D as a backend for physics.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll have a look at it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think nowadays your best choice is [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/features.html). It is a cross-platform game engine, for Android, iOS, desktop and others, has a really active community, is still actively developed and has Box2D and Bullet physics engines integrated.

The framework is really great and there have been really successful games using this engine, even on Steam.