# Water enclosed in body with floating balls game in iPhone

Tags: iphone, mobile, cocos2d-iphone, ipod-touch

This is my first post in stackoverflow so kindly bear with if i make any mistakes.

I am trying to develop an iphone game with water enclosed in a container with balls .
I am not sure how to get about with the effects that would be required and which framework would be suitable for this work.
Kindly anyone could direct me with some help would be greatly appreciated. 
Also the tutorials i would require during this process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need a [physics engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_engine) to model the ball movement.

See the related question for information about physics engines that will run in the iPhone:  [Is there any physics engine SDK for iPhone/iPod touch and iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695724/is-there-any-physics-engine-sdk-for-iphone-ipod-touch-and-ipad)